# filling in variable values using R

Tags: r, variables

I have a large data set and need to fill in just a few missing values. Is there a way to fill in the missing values using R. Here is an example data set:

```
aid weight  birth_date  number_born
1   121 10/02/2009  14
2   111 10/02/2009  NA
3   132 NA           12
4   145 14/02/2009  11
5   221 NA           NA
6   131 25/02/2009  10
7   231 25/02/2009  NA
```

Need to fill in the following  information:

```
Aid = 3, birth_date = 13/02/2009
Aid = 5, birth_date = 17/02/2009
Aid = 2, number_born = 6
Aid = 5, number_born = 16
Aid = 7, number_born = 5
```

I hope that my question is clear enough and any help would be appreciated.

Poasa

Answer (score 1):

If you have data with missing values in data.frame df_with_missing and data to fill in data.frame fill_birth_date (fill_number_born). I assume aid variable is unique in df_with_missing.

```
aid birth_date
3 13/02/2009
5 17/02/2009

fill_birth_date$rec <- match(fill_birth_date$aid,df_with_missing$aid)
df_with_missing$birth_date[fill_birth_date$rec] <- fill_birth_date$birth_date

fill_number_born$rec <- match(fill_number_born$aid,df_with_missing$aid)
df_with_missing$number_born[fill_number_born$rec] <- fill_number_born$number_born
```

Comment: You should coerce (or read) birth_date as character(not factor).